# How to drop rows from a list of data frames

Tags: pandas, loops, nested-lists

I have a list (size 5) where each element is a 1000x2 data frame.
Each data frame looks like this:

| timestamp| Speed    |
| -------- | -------- |
| 00:00:00 |  100
| 00:00:05 | 120      |
| 00:00:10 | 20       |
and so on..(There are 5 of them in the list)
Suppose I want to drop rows where speed is below 50 from each data frame.

I know I can do that for certain data frame (=element in the list, lets say I am working on the second data frame=list_A[1]) as follows;
`a=(list_A[1]['speed']<50) b = list_A[1]['timestamp'][a] df1=list_A[1][~list_A[1]['timestamp'].isin(b)]` 
But how can I iterate over all the element in the list and have the result (with rows whose speed is over 50) in the original list format?

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumarate` for indexing list of DataFrames and assign in for loop:

```
for i, x in enumerate(list_A):
    list_A[i] = x[~x['timestamp'].isin(x.loc[x['speed']<50, 'timestamp'])]
```